# Map mouse position from hwnd to HWND_DESKTOP

Tags: windows, winapi, point

Hello how i can map mouse position from local area window to screen window?

```
in code :
//Get x & y mouse coord...
Point.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
Point.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);  
//Translate to Screen 
MapWindowPoints(hWnd, HWND_DESKTOP, &Point, 1);
//not work!
SetCursorPos(Point.x, Point.y);
```

ok try next..

```
 POINT Point;
 Point.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
 Point.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);  
 ClientToScreen(hWnd, &Point); 
 SetCursorPos(Point.x, Point.y); // not work!
```

[image]

Comment: `ClientToScreen` is presumably what you want. I guess your code is broken, or your understanding. Hard to say with an incomplete fragment and a description of the problem that says nothing more than "not work". The question "not work". Please visit the [help], read the articles, and come back with a better question, including a [mcve].

Comment: i wanna map mouse position from "MyApp" HWND to global (HWND_DESKTOP). if i click mouse on position (x y) on MyAPP, this shall be mapped to Global Screen.

Comment: Yes, you said so already. You just ignored my comment though didn't you? You don't want to read anything, you just want somebody to do your job for you. We aren't here for that. If you want personal one to one support, this is the wrong place, look elsewhere. If you are prepared to ask a good quality question that adds value to this site, please edit it accordingly. Now, you have some reading to do.

Comment: `ClientToScreen` not scale. it simply add offset of your window (+border with/heigh) to client coordinate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saying something "not work!" is not helpful. Are the x and y coordinates what you expect?

Converting LPARAM client coordinates to screen coordinates and calling `SetCursorPos` is not going to move the mouse because the mouse pointer is already there!

If your application is not DPI-aware and you are running on a high DPI system then the coordinates of your application might not be the real coordinates but in your case I'm guessing that you are just not setting x and y to the "correct" values.